# How to redirect from Facebook notification not to: https://apps.facebook.com/appname/ but to: www.example.com?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

How to redirect from Facebook notification not to: https://apps.facebook.com/appname/

but to: www.example.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Give `redirect_uri=www.example.com` in your code as well as give this same url in you facebook application settings page (Site url)